# Making Cloud Storage files public via the file package?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

In Google Developer Console's Cloud Storage browser, there is an option to make files public, allowing anybody to access the file via the URI. I am using the Go file package which implements a client for Cloud Storage to Create files in Cloud Storage. Is there any way to make these files public via the file package? Docs are not clear about this: https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/appengine-go/appengine/file.

Comment: In Python I can set the acl to public when I write the file. See this GIST: https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133 : gcs_write_blob()

Comment: Thanks. But I'm in a Go environment.

Comment: I know. But the API will not be very different. Hope this helps.